# Can not find -lvl when using compile vlfeat library

Tags: c++, vlfeat

I try to use VLFEAT in my own project. Follow the instructions provided in its main page, I still have a question.

First, I compile the library using g++ 'make ARCH=glnx86'.It seems OK.And then I use a small program to check whether it is compiled correctly.

```
extern "C" {
#include <vl/generic.h>
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
VL_PRINT ("Hello world!") ;
return 0;
}
```

I use the following script to compile:

```
 $ g++ main.cpp -o vlfeat-test -IVLROOT -LVLROOT/bin/glnx86/ -lvl
```

VLROOT is short for the path of vlfeat in my computer.

It is failed!!
And the error message is:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvl
```

I know the -l flag is used to tell g++ which static library should be linked. In this case, it seems 'libvl.a' is needed. However, I check the vlfeat,and it does't have 'libvl.a'. Only dynamic lib 'libvl.so' is found.

Does't the vlfeat itself provide static library? And How to fix this error so that I can use it in my own project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `'$'` sign to properly use the value of your `VLROOT` variable:

```
export VLROOT=/path/to/vlfeat
g++ vl.cpp -o vlfeat-test -I$VLROOT -L$VLROOT/bin/glnx86/ -lvl
```

Then to make sure the dynamic loader finds the library you can do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VLROOT/bin/glnx86/
./vlfeat-test
```

Or alternatively copy `libvl.so` e.g under `/usr/local/lib` and run `ldconfig` to refresh the cache.

See [`dlopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) for more details.